# How to pack properly in this Tkinter script?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning about Tkinter and trying to create a normal looking chat style window. However, when resizing the window there are some unexpected results, such as a gray frame appearing between the items, despite setting expand=1.

Also how can I set it so the space is shared when resizing the window to be smaller than the original?

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        frame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.msgfield = Text(self, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        self.msgfield.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.msgfield.config(state=DISABLED)

        self.inputbox = Text(self, height=2, width=30)
        self.inputbox.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM, expand=0)
        self.inputbox.bind('<Return>', self.retrieve_input)

        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=BOTTOM)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=TOP)

    def retrieve_input(self, event):
        msg = self.inputbox.get(1.0, END)[:-1]

        self.msgfield.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.msgfield.insert(END, msg)
        self.msgfield.see(END)             # Scroll if necessary
        self.msgfield.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.inputbox.delete(0.0, END)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x400+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are packing both your `msgfield` and `inputbox` into `self` instead of `frame`, and `self` is the Tk instance which acts a bit different than a Frame. Try packing into your frame and I think you'll get the behaviour you want (note I added a black border to the Text widget so I could see it):

```
from Tkinter import *


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent

        frame = Frame(self, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.msgfield = Text(frame, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        self.msgfield.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.msgfield.config(state=DISABLED)

        self.inputbox = Text(frame, height=2, width=30, borderwidth=2)
        self.inputbox.config(highlightbackground="Black")
        self.inputbox.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM, expand=0)
        self.inputbox.bind('<Return>', self.retrieve_input)

        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=BOTTOM)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def retrieve_input(self, event):
        msg = self.inputbox.get(1.0, END)[:-1]

        self.msgfield.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.msgfield.insert(END, msg)
        self.msgfield.see(END)             # Scroll if necessary
        self.msgfield.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.inputbox.delete(0.0, END)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x400+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```